# How to use decimals (0.01) in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

I want to make this project: codepen.io/samuelbeard/pen/Dsdie, to where when you upgrade, it will increment to 0.01 Click Per Second Automatically, instead of 1 click per second. I am pretty sure this has to do with a function, but I am a beginner and cant find anything to change it, and dont have the knowledge. Is there a variable I have to change, or what?

Here are some variables I have so far, but the code might be more helpful to see:

```
//variables
var clicks = 0; //increment this by one every click
var auto_clicks = 0; //automatically click once per second
var cost = 1; //the cost of this should increase exponentially
var upgrade_speed = 0; //the level of the speed up upgrade
var click_rate = 1000; //ms between each autoclick
var interval_auto; //storing our interval here so we can update it
var click_increment = 1; //how many clicks per click
//functions

function update_total_clicks() { //updates the number of clicks   
    var e = document.getElementById("total_clicks");
    e.innerHTML = clicks;
}

function buy_something(c, button) {
    if (clicks < c) {
        button.className = 'btn btn-danger';
        setTimeout(function() {
            var e = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0];
            e.className = 'btn btn-success';
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
    clicks -= c;
    return true;
}

function update_workers() {
    var e2 = document.getElementById("time_period");
    e2.innerHTML = parseFloat(click_rate / 1000.0).toFixed(2);
    clearInterval(interval_auto);
    interval_auto = setInterval(function() {
        clicks += auto_clicks;
        update_total_clicks();
    }, click_rate);
}
//click events
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function() {
    clicks = parseFloat(clicks) + parseFloat(click_increment);
    update_total_clicks(); //updates the text
};
document.getElementById("buy_click").onclick = function() {
    if (!buy_something(cost, this)) return;
    auto_clicks++;
    cost = Math.pow(2, auto_clicks); //new cost
    update_total_clicks();
    var e = document.getElementById("clicks_per_second");
    e.innerHTML = auto_clicks;
    var e2 = document.getElementById("buy_click");
    e2.innerHTML = 'Buy for ' + cost;
    var e2 = document.getElementById("autoclicker_level");
    e2.innerHTML = 'lvl  ' + auto_clicks;
};
document.getElementById("upgrade_speed").onclick = function() {
    var upgrade_cost = (Math.pow(3, upgrade_speed)) * 100;
    if (!buy_something(upgrade_cost, this)) return;
    upgrade_speed++;
    click_rate = click_rate * 0.90;
    update_workers();
    var e2 = document.getElementById("upgrade_speed");
    e2.innerHTML = 'Buy for ' + ((Math.pow(3, upgrade_speed)) * 100);
    var e2 = document.getElementById("speed_level");
    e2.innerHTML = 'lvl  ' + upgrade_speed;
};

//Increase Click Increment
document.getElementById("increase_clicks").onclick = function() {
    var upgrade_cost = (Math.pow(3, click_increment)) * 1;
    if (!buy_something(upgrade_cost, this)) return;
    click_increment++;
    update_workers();
    var e2 = document.getElementById("click_increment");
    e2.innerHTML = 'Buy for ' + ((Math.pow(3, click_increment)) * 100);
};

//Start Autoclickers
update_workers();

function set_cookie(cookie_name, value) {
    expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setTime(new Date().getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000));
    var c_value = escape(btoa(JSON.stringify(value))) + "; expires=" + expiry.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function get_cookie(cookie_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + cookie_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(cookie_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) return false;
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1) {
        c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = atob(unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end)));
    return JSON.parse(c_value);
}
```

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Ah ok sorry, I just added more code. I am new to this too, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `click_rate` variable to `10`. The rate is `1000`, which is the value assigned at the start of the program. A click rate of `1` will be 1 millisecond, so it starts at `1000` because 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.